# Filter javascript map object by array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I have an array of keys:

```
var arr = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
```

I also have a Javascript map object containing four keys (var1, var2, var3, var4) and values (1, 2, 3, 4) which I want to filter by the arr-array so I get a new map object only containing the keys (var1, var2, var3) and values (1, 2, 3). Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Can you show us both arrays or objects you want to combine and an example of how you want it to end up?

Comment: I have tried the map/filter/reduce but I haven't got any of them to work @ScottSauyet

Comment: So show your attempts; that way we can explain the flawed assumptions and why those approaches weren't working and then provide a working solution. This way you learn something useful, rather than just being given a black-box solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows little research effort.

Comment: @danielo, it is working my solution for you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can populate a new object using reduce ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)):

```
var map = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var keys = ["b", "c", "d"];

var c = keys.reduce(function(obj, key) {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = map[key];
    return obj;
}, {}); // {b: 2, c: 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `delete` **operator** in order to remove one object' property.

```js
var arr = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
var obj = { var1:1, var2:2, var3:3, var4:4};
var newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
Object.keys(newObj).forEach(function(key){
   if(!arr.includes(key))
    delete newObj[key];
});
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you have the following situation :

```
const keysToKeep = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];
const object = {
  "var1": 1,
  "var2": 2,
  "var3": 3
};
```

If that is the case then you can do the following :

```
const filtered = Object.entries(object)
.filter(e => keysToKeep.includes(e[0]))
.reduce((acc, entrt)=>{
  acc[entry[0]] = entry[1];
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Or

```
const filtered = Object.entries(object)
.map(e => ({
  "key": e[0],
  "value": e[1]
})).filter(e => keysToKeep.includes(e.key))
.reduce((acc, entry)=>{
  acc[entry.key] = entry.value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

This will basically take each entry contained in the object, only keep the entries that have a key that is in the array of keys defined earlier and then reduce it back to an object.