# How can I filter some entries from a Map object?

Tags: javascript

How can I filter some entries from a `Map` object?

I am aware of `Array.prototype.filter()` but `Map.prototype.entries()` returns `Iterator`, not `Array`.

Comment: Would `Array.from()` work ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: please add what you have in the map and what you like to get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter javascript map object by array of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283331/filter-javascript-map-object-by-array-of-keys)

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Sorry, I have just realised it's duplicate. However, I am happy with the `Array.from()` solution, which I wouldn't find in that other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concise way is to convert it to an array and back again:

```js
const m1 = new Map([['foo', 'foo'], ['bar', 'bar']]);
const m2 = new Map([...m1.entries()].filter(([prop]) => prop !== 'foo'));
console.log(...m2.entries());
```

Comment: You can also use Array.from(), then create the new Map with the Array as parameter. Exemple : `new Map(Array.from(map1).filter([...]))`

Comment: I have tried `spread syntax` and `Array.from`. They both work! Thank you.

Comment: @Wit Don't forget to check the answer as valid :)